# How do I calculate the revenue earned per person and per year

Tags: sql, mariadb, dbeaver

I suppose it is quite simple, I just can't get the hang of it.
At the moment I have the following code:

```sql
SELECT s.first_name, s.last_name, s.staff_id, SUM(p.amount) AS 'Revenue'
  FROM payment p
  JOIN staff s
    ON s.staff_id = p.staff_id
 GROUP BY s.staff_id
```

This gives me the 2 staff members and their revenue but I'm still missing the yearly part.

I'm yet again using the sakila database, if anybody could help me I would really appreciate it, thanks in regards

Edit for the tables:

```
-- sakila.staff definition

CREATE TABLE `staff` (
  `staff_id` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `first_name` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `last_name` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `address_id` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `picture` blob DEFAULT NULL,
  `email` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `store_id` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `active` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
  `username` varchar(16) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(40) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_update` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp() ON UPDATE current_timestamp(),
  PRIMARY KEY (`staff_id`),
  KEY `idx_fk_store_id` (`store_id`),
  KEY `idx_fk_address_id` (`address_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_staff_address` FOREIGN KEY (`address_id`) REFERENCES `address` (`address_id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_staff_store` FOREIGN KEY (`store_id`) REFERENCES `store` (`store_id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;


CREATE TABLE `payment` (
  `payment_id` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `customer_id` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `staff_id` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `rental_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `amount` decimal(5,2) NOT NULL,
  `payment_date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `last_update` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp() ON UPDATE current_timestamp(),
  PRIMARY KEY (`payment_id`),
  KEY `idx_fk_staff_id` (`staff_id`),
  KEY `idx_fk_customer_id` (`customer_id`),
  KEY `fk_payment_rental` (`rental_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_payment_customer` FOREIGN KEY (`customer_id`) REFERENCES `customer` (`customer_id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_payment_rental` FOREIGN KEY (`rental_id`) REFERENCES `rental` (`rental_id`) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_payment_staff` FOREIGN KEY (`staff_id`) REFERENCES `staff` (`staff_id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=16050 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
```

Comment: We can't help you without seeing your `CREATE TABLE` statements. Also, you haven't posted any details about how you're storing date/time information or what the `payment` table actually represents.

Comment: You should be using double-quotes to escape column names, not single-quotes (i.e. use `AS "Revenue"` not `AS 'Revenue'`. MySQL/MariaDB is very forgiving when it comes to SQL syntax, but it helps to stick to ISO SQL for maximum portability.

Comment: Also, please explain your terminology -  "revenue" is the term for *incoming* money, and salaries/wages would be *outgoing* money, so as-it-is your DB design and column names are confusing (at least for people unfamiliar with your business/domain model, i.e. us random SO users)

Comment: In terms of naming I have trouble differentiating those 2, after your explanation I can see that  I may need the revenue. And in terms of the create table code I'll try to add it to the main question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done by simply adding the year to the `GROUP BY` clause, like this:

```sql
SELECT s.first_name, s.last_name, s.staff_id, SUM(p.amount) AS 'Revenue'
     , YEAR(payment_date) AS year
  FROM payment p
  JOIN staff s
    ON s.staff_id = p.staff_id
 GROUP BY s.staff_id, year
;
```

This means, generate a `SUM` for each group associated with rows having the same `(staff_id, year)` pairs.

The result:

```
+------------+-----------+----------+----------+------+
| first_name | last_name | staff_id | Revenue  | year |
+------------+-----------+----------+----------+------+
| Mike       | Hillyer   |        1 | 33255.38 | 2005 |
| Mike       | Hillyer   |        1 |   234.09 | 2006 |
| Jon        | Stephens  |        2 | 33646.95 | 2005 |
| Jon        | Stephens  |        2 |   280.09 | 2006 |
+------------+-----------+----------+----------+------+
```